# Google Drive API - Search by file name only finds the file if it has recently been opened via Google Drive on chrome

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a method that will search for a file by name and then download that file:

```
    public static void DownloadFile(string filename)
    {
        service = GetDriveService();

        //check if file exists and grab id 
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
        listRequest.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
        listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
        listRequest.Q = "name = '" + filename + ".pdf'";
        FileList files = listRequest.Execute();

        if (files.Files.Count > 0) //the file exists, DOWNLOAD
        {
            var request = service.Files.Get(files.Files[0].Id);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            request.Download(stream);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `FileList files = listRequest.Execute();` will return 0 files unless I have recently opened that file on Google Drive in Chrome. it's like the files are not indexed. Am I missing a parameter?

I've tested this on loads of files and without fail, if I've opened the file on chrome `FileList files = listRequest.Execute();` returns 1 element otherwise it returns nothing.

I have also tested searching in specific folders only, same issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

thanks

edit; Here is the GetDriveService Method:

```
 private static DriveService GetDriveService()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }; // Full access

        GoogleDrive cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleDrive>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\PATH_TO_JSONFILE\GoogleAPI.json")); 
                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ServiceAccountCredential xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email)
        {
            User = "xxxxx@xxxx.xx",
            Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
        }.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));

        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = xCred,
            ApplicationName = "APPLICATION_NAME",
        });
        return service;
    }
```

The `User` email is the same account I use to open the files in Chrome.

Comment: Can i see the code you are using to authorize your application.   GetDriveService  <-- that method.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.

In GetDriveService() the `User` was set to my own email address and not to the service account address with account-wide delegation across our organisation.

I guess my email-address did not 'own' the files until I opened them once.

Hope this can prevent someone from doing the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this happens if you are defaulting to the "user" corpora and the files haven't been directly shared with you (i.e. you've been aliased in to having access instead).

In the case that you can't use a service account for what you're doing, you can fix this issue by changing the corpora parameter to "allDrives" instead.

So in your C# DownloadFile method just add

```
listRequest.Corpora="allDrives";
```